# Lagom embedded Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, lagom

Running `sbt runAll` yields the following result:

```
[info] Starting Cassandra
.
[info] Cassandra server is not yet started.
[info] 
[info] The value assigned to
[info] `lagomCassandraMaxBootWaitingTime`
[info] is either too short, or this may indicate another
[info] process is already running on port 4000
```

Nothing runs on port 4000. I have tried to configure a different port, but the message persists (with the different port).
By default, 20 seconds should be sufficient, I strongly doubt that this is the problem.

No idea how to debug this or what may the cause of this.
I realise that I could run a local Cassandra server, but I wish to get this working.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that increasing the timeout actually worked as described in the documentation:

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._ // Mind that the import is needed.
lagomCassandraMaxBootWaitingTime in ThisBuild := 50000.seconds
```

It's probably a problem with my PC, the build is extremely slow.
I will investigate this further.